# Would entropy increase even in the colder regions of the universe?

Tags: temperature, entropy, universe, space

We know that entropy increases as temperature increases. However, in the colder regions of the universe, temperature is low. Does that mean entropy in the universe stops increasing as temperature falls in the outer regions of space?

Comment: Entropy and temperature are independent: you can vary one without necessarily varying the other.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try and provide a very simple and generic answer. First, we need to understand what entropy is. It is just the degree of disorderliness. You increase the temperature, things start to move more and there is more disorder and you have more entropy. It's not that entropy depends on temperature but the effects of what increasing the temperature have on the system. So the question we should be asking is:

What else would allow an increase in disorder if you can't change the temperature? Now let's talk about volume. If you increase the volume, you increase the possible number of distributions that the molecules can now have. Water in a glass has only so much volume that there can be only so many possible distributions and therefore so little disorder. Now when the water is on the floor, it has more volume, that allows it to be more disorderly than before and more disorderly it gets.

Now to answer your question. In colder regions, the volume is still increasing because space itself is expanding.

Comment: It is not correct to say that entropy is "temperature independent". It does depend on temperature, just in a material-specific way.

Comment: You are right, I will update the answer to better written one. I wasn't trying to say what I wrote.